# Python: How to validate input file line-by-line, fix possible errors, and write cleaned lines to another file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, validation

My lines in the text file look like this :

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3350.0,387.0,3353.0,388.0
```

The number at `1915` location should always be smaller than the element at `1933` location, and the element at `387` location should always be smaller than the element at `402` location.

Unfortunately it isn't always the case as my data isn't perfectly clean. To fix that, I want to create another file where I just copy the line if it's correct and do the necessary adjustment fixing it in the new file if it isn't (I don't want to manipulate the data in the original file).

My code:

```
path = 'data/faulty.txt'
with open(path ) as f:
    with open('data/true_values.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        for line in f:
            numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            if numbers:
                if numbers[2] > numbers[6]:
                    temp = numbers[2]
                    numbers[2] = numbers[6]
                    numbers[6] = temp

                if numbers[4] > numbers[8]:
                    temp = numbers[2]
                    numbers[2] = numbers[6]
                    numbers[6] = temp

                the_file.write(line)
```

How can I make the change into the line? I also thought about using `re.sub` but couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: for swaping values do it pythonic way, `a,b = b,c`

Comment: That way and what i'm doing too is swapping the values in the list `numbers` but what i want to do is to swap them in `line` so that won't fix my issue but thanks.

Comment: @Allen of course it won't "swap them in line" - you have to recreate the line from the (possibly) swapped values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

example without `re`:

```
input_filename = 'full_path_to_my_input_file.txt'
output_filename = 'full_path_to_my_output_file.txt'

with open(output_filename, 'a') as f_out:
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            records = line.strip().split(',')
            if float(records[1]) > float(records[3]):
                records[1], records[3] = records[3], records[1]
            if float(records[2]) > float(records[4]):
                records[2], records[4] = records[4], records[2]
            f_out.write(','.join(records) + '\n')
```

input:

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3353.0,389.0,3350.0,388.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,952.0,724.0,1010.0,734.0
```

output:

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3350.0,388.0,3353.0,389.0 ## swapped !!
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,952.0,724.0,1010.0,734.0
```

Comment: I had this line in my data `data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,952.0,724.0,1010.0,734.0` for some reason it became `data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1010.0,724.0,952.0,734.0`

Comment: @Allen updated answer to use float() for comparisson

Answer (score 1):

I'd write the modified lines to a list as you go, then write the list out to a file at the end. that way you're not holding both files open while you process the first, which makes it more atomic an operation. Have also fixed to make the regex hand'e floats which I missed earlier.

```
import re

input = "data/faulty.txt"
output = "data/true_values.txt"
new = []

with open(input) as f:
    for line in f:
        name, numberstr = line.split(',', 1)
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+', numberstr)
        if numbers:
            if numbers[0] > numbers[2]:
                numbers[0], numbers[2] = numbers[2], numbers[0]
            if numbers[1] > numbers[3]:
                numbers[1], numbers[3]  = numbers[3], numbers[1]

        new.append("{},{}".format(name, ','.join(numbers)))

with open(output, 'a') as the_file:
    for x in new:
        the_file.write(x + '\n')
```

Comment: Won't this code change my original data?, if yes i don't want any modification there i want all the changes in a new file

Comment: no, he's writing to a new file. If you're that sensitive about the original data, just open that file in READ mode.

Comment: Yep - `open` defaults to `'r'` so the original file won't get modified at all.

Answer (score 1):

i believe its possible without using `re`

try running this

```
with open(path) as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as outputFile:
        for line in f:
            lineArr = line.split(",")
            if float(lineArr[1])>float(lineArr[3]):
                lineArr[1], lineArr[3] = lineArr[3].replace("\n",""), lineArr[1].replace("\n","")
            if float(lineArr[2])>float(lineArr[4]):
                lineArr[2], lineArr[4] = lineArr[4].replace("\n",""), lineArr[2].replace("\n","")
            lineArr.append("\n")
            outputFile.write(",".join(lineArr))
```

Comment: writes output without \n ... all on one line

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexps when they're not the right tool. You obviously have a csv format, so use the csv module. Also, you need to convert your "numbers" to actual numbers - what you read in are strings not numbers. And finally, once you have parsed and possibly fixed a line, you have to recreate the new one from "fixed" values before you write it back:

```
# XXX untested code, may contains typos or small bugs
import csv

inpath = 'data/faulty.txt'
outpath = 'data/true_values.txt'
with open(inpath) as infile, open(outpath, 'a') as outpath:

    # please check the csv doc for the correct options for your file format
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delim=",")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delim=",")

    for row in reader:
        # split the path from the numbers
        imagepath, nums = row[0], row[1:]

        # convert numbers to floats so we have
        # meaningful comparisons
        nums = [float(num) for num in nums]

        # swap the numbers if necessary
        if nums[0] > nums[2]:
            nums[2], nums[0] = nums[0], nums[2] 
        if nums[1] > nums[3]:
            nums[3], nums[1] = nums[1], nums[3] 

        # recreate the fixed row and write it
        newrow = [imagepath] + nums
        writer.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: I like this one best

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'data/faulty.txt'
with open(path, "r") as f, open('data/true_values.txt', "a") as the_file:
        for line in f:
                lineArr = line[:-1].split(",")    
                if float(lineArr[1])>float(lineArr[3]):
                        lineArr[1], lineArr[3] = lineArr[3], lineArr[1]
                if float(lineArr[2])>float(lineArr[4]):
                        lineArr[2], lineArr[4] = lineArr[4], lineArr[2]
                the_file.write(",".join(lineArr) + "\n")
```

`lineArr = line[:-1].split(",")` So that you don't get the new line character with the last element of the list else when you do this it will input a new line character when and if the last number is swapped. Try this on the inputs I provided to understand it's importance `lineArr = line.split(",")`

Using `split` you get a `list` in which `slicing` can be used to get the data which is converted into `float` and value is compared and if they are not what you wanted they will be `swapped`.

data/faulty.txt  :

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1234.5,387.0,1222.1,380.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3350.0,387.0,3353.0,388.0
```

After running the python script.

data/true_values.txt :

```
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1222.1,380.0,1234.5,387.0  #Swapped
data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3350.0,387.0,3353.0,388.0
```

Comment: why are you using non-standard indentation // spacing ?

Comment: Now I did. Sorry for posting in a hurry

Answer (score 0):

This should work (stripped away the file access to be able to replicate the problem):

```
input = ['data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,1915.0,387.0,1933.0,402.0',
'data/processed/10/blueprint-0.png,3353.0,387.0,3350.0,388.0']

output = []
for input_line in input:
    numbers = input_line.split(',')
    if numbers:
        if float(numbers[1]) > float(numbers[3]):
            numbers[1], numbers[3] = numbers[3], numbers[1]

        if float(numbers[2]) > float(numbers[4]):
            numbers[2], numbers[4] = numbers[4], numbers[2]

    output.append(','.join(numbers))

print(output)
```